# Drupal dynamic product catalog (without commerce)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

So, I work at a web development agency and we recently decided to give our custom CMS up and start developing with **Drupal**. Currently, I am developing a [**wholesale product website**](http://demo.mpomponiera-marianthi.gr/). What I need to do is to create some **product catalogs** without using commerce since we do not need the purchase, checkout and payment features and I thought that using the built-in **Content, Taxonomy** and **Views** features we can get our job done.

I have created the product categories in **Taxonomy**. The main (root) categories are **main Taxonomy objects** and the subcategories are **terms**.

I created a custom Content type called: **products**. In this type I have the following form fields: *Product Code, Name, Image, Description* and a *list field* to choose the **Terms** I would like the product to be displayed in.

I would appreciate some help in order to set the whole structure up as I am still heavily influenced by the custom CMS we used to work on that had similar content management with Joomla!

**In conclusion, I would like to:**

1. Set a sidebar menu up that contains the categories and the subcategories as a tree. I would also like the menu to be updated if any changes occur in the taxonomy (e.g I add a term in taxonomy and it shows up on the menu).
2. Set the structure so that when someone clicks on a category that does NOT contain products but subcategories, gets the list of the categories bellow the active one.

I am really looking forward to your answers and I'd like to thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a try to a combination of [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) modules. Taxonomy Menu allows you to easily generate menus from taxonomy vocabularies, and Menu Block creates menus and "menus portion", for instance, from level 2 to 3 from a specific point.

So basically, you can create menus from taxonomy and then create submenus from those menus with Menu Block. It can be tricky but you can do a lot of things with these modules.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Any ideas on how I integrate the Taxonomy Menu with views ? There is not enough documentation for that part

Comment: If you need to modify taxonomy terms default pages (from your comment I assume it's the goal), you can override the default view which handles /taxonomy/term/% URLs, or try Taxonomy Display module : https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display. This question could be helpful too : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27682/how-do-i-override-a-taxonomy-term-list-with-a-view